# I want to get all those elements that are missing from first Array

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays.

```
$first = Array
(
    [01/10/2019] => Array
    (
        [0] => 21498226
        [1] => 21497647
        [2] => 21497649
        [3] => 21497635
        [4] => 21497636
        [5] => 21497637
        [6] => 21497728
        [7] => 21497822
        [8] => 21498028
        [9] => 21497638
        [10] => 21497738
    )

)

$second = Array
(
    [01/10/2019] => Array
    (
        [0] => 21498226
        [1] => 21497647
        [2] => 12345678
        [3] => 87654321
        [4] => 21497636
        [5] => 21497637
        [6] => 21497728
        [7] => 21497822
        [8] => 21498028
        [9] => 21497638
    )
)
```

I have written this code

```
$notPresent = [];
$notPresent = array_combine(
    array_keys($first),
    array_map(function ($key, $values) use ($second) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $second)) {
            return array_diff($values, $second[$key]);
        }
        return $values;
    }, array_keys($first), array_values($first))
);
```

I want to get all the elements missing from $first. But this code is returning me just 3 values where as I have 4 such values. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)?

Comment: Yes but it returns empty array.

Comment: use [array_diif](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) :- https://3v4l.org/GPfMC (values of first which are not in second)  OR https://3v4l.org/GDYQF (values of second which are not in first)

Comment: There can me multiple keys in each array. It should be generic.

Comment: `$tempArrayOne = array_values($first)[0];
 $tempArrayTwo = array_values($second)[0];
$res = array_diff($tempArrayOne, $tempArrayTwo);
`

Comment: @sibabratswain why have you used [0] ?

Comment: I don't see 4 different values in your data. There are 3 different between 1 and 2, and 2 different between 2 and 1

Comment: There is only 3 differenct elements are there, i have tried below code and get 3 diff element

Comment: you want which are not available in `$first`. So 
try with this one 
`$res = array_diff($tempArrayTwo, tempArrayOne);` 

There are two of $second array which is not present in $first array. (Those are `12345678, 87654321`)